# How to Rescue From An Error in Rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How do I rescue from a

> undefined method

```
error in this code

for user in @users do
    @customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(user.stripe_customer_token)
        if @customer.subscription.nil?
        elsif @customer.subscription.plan.id == 2
          user.silver_reset
        elsif @customer.subscription.plan.id == 3
          user.gold_reset
      end
    end
```

I have tried a plain rescue call, but rake isn't liking it.

What is way to rescue from the error?

UPDATE:

The way I was doing it

```
 for    user in @users do
            @customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(user.stripe_customer_token)
         rescue_from Exception => exception
          # Logic
        end
        if @customer.subscription.nil?
        elsif @customer.subscription.plan.id == 2
          user.silver_reset
        elsif @customer.subscription.plan.id == 3
          user.gold_reset
      end
    end
```

The Error
/home/user/rails_projects/assignitapp/lib/tasks/daily.rake:25: syntax error, unexpected keyword_rescue, expecting keyword_end
         rescue Exception => exception

Rake 0.9.2.2
Rails 3.2.5

Comment: How are you trying to rescue?

Comment: "Rake isn't liking it"—what was the code you tried and what error or behavior were you getting?

Comment: Added the info Henrique and Jordon asked for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`try`](http://everydayrails.com/2011/04/28/rails-try-method.html) to wrap the problem method and return nil if it doesn't exist. E.g.:

```
unless @customer = Stripe::Customer.try(:retrieve, user.stripe_customer_token)
  # Logic
end
```

Alternatively, this catches more errors:

```
unless @customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(user.stripe_customer_token) rescue nil
  # Logic
end
```

Or this is more what you were trying for:

```
@users.each do |user|
  begin
    @customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(user.stripe_customer_token)
  rescue StandardError => error
     # handle error
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I still haven't enough reputation to comment, but regarding the above answer's third option: **Don't rescue from Exception!**

`Exception` is the root of Ruby's exception hierarchy, so when you `rescue Exception` you rescue from *everything*, including subclasses such as `SyntaxError`, `LoadError`, and `Interrupt`.

If you want to learn more, check out [Why is it a bad style to `rescue Exception => e` in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby)