# NoMethodError (undefined method `flush' for Logger at Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

When I uploaded the Rails app to Heroku, I got an error using heroku logs

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `flush' for #<Logger:0x00000005501680>):
2012-12-20T16:20:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:19:in `block in <class:ApplicationController>'
```

it was because of

```
 rescue_from 'Exception' do |ex|
    Rails.logger.fatal formatted_exception(ex)
    Rails.logger.flush
```

in `ApplicationController`.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flush is a method defined on IO, which flushes the buffered output to the pipe.

Given the multi-environment setup of Heroku, they probably have their own implementation of the IO pipes, which may not have flush defined. If Flush isn't defined, it's a fairly safe bet you don't need it, and it flushes automatically on receiving input.

How about

```
rescue_from 'Exception' do |ex|
  Rails.logger.fatal formatted_exception(ex)
  Rails.logger.flush if Rails.logger.respond_to? :flush
```

P.S.

You probably shouldn't rescue Exception: [Why is it a bad style to `rescue Exception => e` in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby)