# unable to catch ruby exception

Tags: ruby, exception, mongoid3, moped

Having the following, long running rake batch:

```
class SyncStarredRepo
  include Mongoid::Document

  def self.update

    User.all.map do |user| 

      if user.email != "admin@gitwatcher.com"
        begin 
          conn = Faraday.new "https://api.github.com" 
          i = 1  
          begin   
            resp = conn.get "/users/#{user.nickname}/starred?page=#{i}"
            resp.body.each do |repo|
              attempts = 0
              begin 
                existing_repo = user.watchlists.where( html_url: "#{repo['html_url']}" ).batch_size(30)
                if existing_repo.exists?  
                  existing_repo.first.update_attributes!(
                      html_url: "#{repo['html_url']}",
                      description: "#{repo['description']}"
                  )
                else   
                  user.watchlists.create!(
                      html_url: "#{repo['html_url']}",
                      description: "#{repo['description']}"
                  )
                end

              rescue Moped::Errors::CursorNotFound => c
                attempts += 1
                puts "error message: #{c.message}"
                if attempts < 3
                  puts "Retrying... Attempt #: #{attempts.to_s}"
                  sleep(3)
                  retry 
                else 
                  puts "already retried 3 times, go to the next"
                  next
                end
              end

            end  
            i += 1 
          end until resp.body.empty? 

        rescue TypeError => e
          puts "message error (e.inspect): #{e.inspect}"
          puts "go to the next user"
          next    
        rescue  
          p $!, *$@
          next    
        end  
      end  

    end 
  end
end
```

I aspected to catch Moped::Errors::CursorNotFound exception but it doesn't work.

In the crontab log I just get this message :

```
rake aborted!
The operation: "GET MORE"
failed with error "cursor 2509315744412059250 not found"
```

then the batch stops and exit, while I was aspecting the rescue messages and next loop operation.

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to "extend" catchable exception set to **StandardError**, by doing this :

```
      rescue
        p $!, *$@
        next
      end
```

... just in case, even if **CursorNotFound** inherit from **MongoError**, which inherit from **StandardError**, as you can see [here](https://codeclimate.com/github/mongoid/moped/Moped%3a%3aErrors%3a%3aCursorNotFound).

**UPDATE**

I just updated previous simplified code, with the full **SyncStarredRepo** class used by rake, just in case I was missing something into the loop logic, begin/rescue/end and so on ...

**UPDATE**

follow the stacktrace printed by `rake -t` :

```
rake aborted!
The operation: "GET MORE"
failed with error "cursor 5781947091640256877 not found"
/var/www/gitwatcher/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/node.rb:210:in `get_more'
/var/www/gitwatcher/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cursor.rb:44:in `get_more'
/var/www/gitwatcher/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cursor.rb:29:in `each'
/var/www/gitwatcher/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/query.rb:77:in `each'
/var/www/gitwatcher/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/query.rb:77:in `each'
/var/www/gitwatcher/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-92cad16e9fbf/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:133:in `block in each'
/var/www/gitwatcher/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-92cad16e9fbf/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:605:in `selecting'
/var/www/gitwatcher/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-92cad16e9fbf/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:132:in `each'
/var/www/gitwatcher/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-92cad16e9fbf/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:18:in `each'
/var/www/gitwatcher/app/models/sync_starred_repo.rb:15:in `map'
/var/www/gitwatcher/app/models/sync_starred_repo.rb:15:in `update'
/var/www/gitwatcher/lib/tasks/scheduler.rake:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.8/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => update_starred_list_per_user
```

Comment: Not 100% sure but could it be because the exception was thrown inside the second `begin` block? What happens if you move the rescue inside the inner `begin` block?

Comment: I'm trying ... but the run takes one our more or less ... I'll update as soon as possible

Comment: @freakyDaz That doesn’t matter. If there's no `rescue` associated with a `begin...end` then the exception just bubbles up normally.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall ... infact, it doesn't work anyway

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace printed by `rake -t $YOUR_TASK`?

Comment: @LucaG.Soave Yes, it does: `begin begin raise end rescue 'saved' end` returns `"saved"` instead of raising because it is rescued.

Comment: @Koraktor I just posted the stacktrace printed by rake -t   (see last UPDATE)

Comment: @LucaG.Soave: I've updated my answer based on the stacktrace. Seems like the problem is much more simple than obvious with the initial information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is raised during `User.all.map` so you have to wrap your `begin`..`rescue` block around that whole statement.

*Old answer based on initial information:*

<strike>You're rescuing outside of your loop, so `retry` doesn't do exactly what you expect (`next` on the other hand will raise a `SyntaxError` (1.9) or `LocalJumpError` (1.8)). In fact, `retry` inside a `rescue` just causes the code inside the `begin`..`rescue` block to run again.</strike>

The right code should look like that:

```
attempts = 0
begin 
  i = 1 
  resp = conn.get "/users/#{user.nickname}/starred?page=#{i}"
  resp.body.each do |repo|
    begin
      existing_repo = user.watchlists.where( html_url: "#{repo['html_url']}" )
      if existing_repo.exists? 
        existing_repo.first.update_attributes!(
            html_url: "#{repo['html_url']}",
            description: "#{repo['description']}"
        )
      else 
        user.watchlists.create!(
            html_url: "#{repo['html_url']}",
            description: "#{repo['description']}"
        )
      end
    rescue Moped::Errors::CursorNotFound => c
      attempts += 1
      puts "error message: #{c.message}"
      if attempts < 3
        puts "Retrying... Attempt #: #{attempts.to_s}"
        sleep(3)
        retry 
      else 
        puts "already retried 3 times, go to the next"
        next
      end
    end
  end 
  i += 1
end until resp.body.empty?
```

Comment: you were right, around the User.all.map statement it catch the exception

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't looked at your code carefully, please note that a bare `rescue` does *not* catch all exceptions. For that, you need `rescue Exception`.

Comment: sure, I know, but that is not a good practice ( see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby )

Comment: That depends on the situation. There are plenty of cases in which it makes sense to catch *all* exceptions, no matter what.

Comment: Ruby sends Interrupt class which is a SignalException to all threads so that when the process gets an INT/Ctrl-C signal, all the threads will unwind and the process will shutdown. If you rescue Exception, you will potentially catch this exception and ignore it, making your thread and process an unkillable computing zombie. Your only choice will be to pull out your kill -9 shotgun and aim for the head.

Comment: And there are cases where you really want to catch such exceptions and provide your own custom handling for them. Try Ctrl-C in `irb`.

Comment: :-) ok, this should not be the case, because CursorNotFound inherit from MongoError, which inherit from StandardError, as you can see here: https://codeclimate.com/github/mongoid/moped/Moped%3a%3aErrors%3a%3aCursorNotFound ... but I'm going to give it a try anyway, just in case :-)