# RSpec retry throw exception and then return value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a retry block

```
 def my_method
    app_instances = []
    attempts = 0
    begin 
      app_instances = fetch_and_rescan_app_instances(page_n, policy_id, policy_cpath)
    rescue Exception
      attempts += 1
      retry unless attempts > 2
      raise Exception 
    end
    page_n += 1
  end
```

where `fetch_and_rescan_app_instances` access the network so can throw an exception.

I want to write an rspec test that it throws an exception first time and doesn't throw an exception second time it gets called, so I can test if the second time it doesn't throw an exception, the my_method won't throw an exeption.

I know i can do `stub(:fetch_and_rescan_app_instances).and_return(1,3)` and first time it returns 1 and second time 3, but I don't know how to do throw an exception first time and return something second time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can calculate the return value in a block:

```
describe "my_method" do
  before do
    my_instance = ...
    @times_called = 0
    my_instance.stub(:fetch_and_rescan_app_instances).and_return do
      @times_called += 1
      raise Exception if @times_called == 1
    end
  end

  it "raises exception first time method is called" do
    my_instance.my_method().should raise_exception
  end

  it "does not raise an exception the second time method is called" do
    begin
      my_instance.my_method()
    rescue Exception
    end
    my_instance.my_method().should_not raise_exception
  end
end
```

Note that you should really not be rescuing from `Exception`, use something more specific. See: [Why is it a bad style to `rescue Exception => e` in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby)

Comment: Added `my_instance` in there so you get `my_instance.stub(:fetch_and_rescan_app_instances)` etc. Calling `stub(:fetch_and_rescan_app_instances)` just like that will not work.

Comment: Great thanks! @shioyama, I udnerstood why not to do rescue Exception, but what if I don't know what kind of exact exception is it gonna throw? I know it's a network call so it might have connection issues or anything else, but not sure what type of exception it would be.

Comment: @Meena, you could try a regular rescue, which just rescues from StandardError.

Comment: Note that when using `allow` syntax (possibly just rspec3 in general) you omit the `and_return`: `allow(my_instance).to receive(:fetch_and_rescan_app_instances) do...`

Answer (score 21):

What you do is constrain the times the message should be received (receive counts), i.e. in your case you can

```
instance.stub(:fetch_and_rescan_app_instances).once.and_raise(RuntimeError, 'fail')
instance.stub(:fetch_and_rescan_app_instances).once.and_return('some return value')
```

Calling `instance.fetch_and_rescan_app_instances` first time will raise RuntimeError, and second time will return 'some return value'.

PS. Calling more than that will result in an error, you might consider using different receive count specification https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/message-expectations/receive-counts

Answer (score 13):

This has changed a little in RSpec3.x. It seems the best approach is to pass a block to the `receive` that defines this type of behaviour.

The following is from the docs suggesting how to create this type of [transit failure](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-5/docs/configuring-responses/block-implementation#simulating-a-transient-network-failure):

(This errors *every other time* it is called... But is easy to adapt.)

```
RSpec.describe "An HTTP API client" do
  it "can simulate transient network failures" do
    client = double("MyHTTPClient")

    call_count = 0
    allow(client).to receive(:fetch_data) do
      call_count += 1
      call_count.odd? ? raise("timeout") : { :count => 15 }
    end

    expect { client.fetch_data }.to raise_error("timeout")
    expect(client.fetch_data).to eq(:count => 15)
    expect { client.fetch_data }.to raise_error("timeout")
    expect(client.fetch_data).to eq(:count => 15)
  end
end
```