# record not found but not sure how - how to get back specific sql call raising this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I think subject says it all. Would something like this work?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from Exception, :with => :bad_call

  def bad_call
    # how would I log the specific sql for ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  end
end
```

Sorry for vague question but should be clear from the question and would be a tremendous help. How would I log this information esp in development?

ths in advance

Comment: I think this is tricky and would require monkeypatching, as the SQL query isn't included as part of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

If I did understand you right then that should be it.

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |exception|
  Rails.logger.info exception
end
```

I'd also suggest reading the topic about [why it is bad to rescue from Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby).

**UPD**: Oh, I guess I'm wrong. That won't give you the SQL query if this is what you need.