# Getting 'message' from a custom exception class

Tags: ruby, exception

This question refers to [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16108216/321629). I need to access `message` of a custom exception. Is this possible?

I thought that directly calling `message` will suffice as in this example:

```
class MyCustomError < StandardError
  attr_reader :object

  def initialize(object)
    @object = object
    puts message
  end
end
```

but this is not what I expected it to be. It gave me some string like:

```
"MyModuleNameHere::MyCustomExceptionClassNameHere"
```

instead of:

```
"a message"
```

My intuition is leaning towards no, since the `initialize` constructor does not take the `"a message"` text.

Comment: What do you actually want to do with the message? You probably don't want to print it within `initialize`.

Answer (score 1):

You get the class name of the error as the default `message` because you have not set anything for `message`. Once you set something, you will get it.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the message and call `super` which will normally take a message, e.g. `StandardError.new("oh no")`.

```
class MyCustomError < StandardError

  def initialize(message, object)
    # ...
    super(message)
  end
end

MyCustomError.new("Oh no", thing).message # => "Oh no"
```

This ebook on Ruby exceptions is well worth it: http://exceptionalruby.com/