# Exception is only caught with `rescue` at the end of the line but not when using a `begin rescue` block

Tags: ruby, exception, rescue

I have a statement that fails:

```
result = service.load_data()
```

Now the following suppresses the error and I can then check for `nil`

```
result = service.load_data() rescue nil
```

But when I do the following the initial error is thrown right up to the UI and I don't get the `details` of the exception.

```
begin
   result = service.load_data()
rescue => details         
   logger.fatal "Failed to load the data: #{details}"
end
```

I am sure there is a silly detail I must be missing but I can't seem to spot the problem here. So why isn't the `rescue` block invoked?

**Update:** The error I got was this:

```
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Comment: What kind of error happens?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known` (I updated my answer)

Comment: Check the spelling of 'rescue' (your post has 'resuce').

Comment: You still haven't provided an exception class, but for anyone trying to help, it's probably `SocketError`

Comment: Also, using `rescue` with no class will default to `StandardError`, if your exception class does not inherit from that, it will fail. You might want `rescue Exception` or specify classes more specifically. That said, if it /is/ SocketError, that inherits from StandardError so your code should work as it is

Comment: @BobJarvis good catch. I corrected it. I did not have this typo in the code though.

Comment: Ok Priti's answer did the trick. I don't know why I am being downvoted. I do find it a bit peculiar that `rescue` at the end of a line cateches the Exception in this case but when used as a block it doesn't unless you provide the type of the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
begin
   result = service.load_data()
rescue AnExceptionKlass => details    # here the name is SocketError    
   logger.fatal "Failed to load the data: #{details}"
end
```

use the above.

*tried to replicate the error here as below:*

```
require 'net/http'
Net::HTTP.start('http://www.google.com') do |http|
response = http.get('/')
puts response
end
#=> getaddrinfo: No such host is known.  (SocketError)
```

*Fixed it as below:*

```
require 'net/http'

begin

  htt = Net::HTTP.start('http://www.google.com')
  response = htt.get('/')
  puts response

rescue SocketError => details    # or the Exception class name may be SocketError    
   p "Failed to load the data: #{details}"
end

#=> "Failed to load the data: getaddrinfo: No such host is known. "
```

Comment: NEVER `rescue Exception => e`  Don't even suggest it as an "example". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby

Comment: @nitsujri Did you read answer completely ? Did you read the comments I gave. come on!!