# Filter out email addresses from ActionMailer logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

When sending emails via Actionmailer in Rails, it logs something like:

```
Sent mail to example@example.com (72ms)
  Rendered mailer/_header.html.erb (0.0ms)
  ...
```

I would like to filter the emails from logs ala parameter filtering

```
Sent mail to [FILTERED] (72ms)
  Rendered mailer/_header.html.erb (0.0ms)
  ...
```

Is there a clean way to do this? Alternatively, not logging the whole first line would be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a monkey-patching for your current action mailer:

1. find gem source code for your version of rails (in my case it's in ~/.rvm/gems/xxx@railsx/gems/actionmailer-x.x.x/lib/action_mailer
2. find a method which contains "Sent mail to"
3. Create a file in your "lib" directory with the content like this (copy and paste the code from the step 2 and change "recipients" to "[FILTERED]":

   ```
   module ActionMailer

   class LogSubscriber < ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber

   def deliver(event)
     return unless logger.info?
     #recipients = Array(event.payload[:to]).join(', ')
     info("\nSent mail to [FILTERED] (#{event.duration.round(1)}ms)")
     debug(event.payload[:mail])
   end

   end

   end
   ```

For my version of action_mailer the code would be like this:

```
def deliver!(mail = @mail)
  raise "no mail object available for delivery!" unless mail
  unless logger.nil?
    logger.info  "Sent mail to [FILTERED]"
    # instead of original logger.info  "Sent mail to #{Array(recipients).join(', ')}"
    logger.debug "\n#{mail.encoded}"
  end

  begin
    __send__("perform_delivery_#{delivery_method}", mail) if perform_deliveries
  rescue Exception => e  # Net::SMTP errors or sendmail pipe errors
    raise e if raise_delivery_errors
  end

  return mail
end
```

Comment: `rescue Exception` is evil
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby

Answer (score 1):

In Rails sourcecode `./actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/log_subscriber.rb`:

```
module ActionMailer
  class LogSubscriber < ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber
    def deliver(event)
      return unless logger.info?
      recipients = Array(event.payload[:to]).join(', ')
      info("\nSent mail to #{recipients} (#{event.duration.round(1)}ms)")
      debug(event.payload[:mail])
    end

    def receive(event)
      return unless logger.info?
      info("\nReceived mail (#{event.duration.round(1)}ms)")
      debug(event.payload[:mail])
    end

    def logger
      ActionMailer::Base.logger
    end
  end
end
```

Rails is not providing a method to filter email, so you can:

- fork rails, remove this info, and use your forked version of rails.
- edit this code, add some filter, and make a pull request.