# What is different between || and rescue?

Tags: ruby

Is there any difference between using the `||` operator and `rescue` in Ruby?

Say:

```
b = A.value || "5"

b = A.value rescue 5
```

where the object `A` does not have `value` method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`||` is the boolean *or* operator (keep in mind that in Ruby, only the values `nil` and `false` evaluates to false, in boolean context):

```
nil || 5
# => 5

false || 5
# => 5

4 || 5
# => 4
```

`rescue` is for exception catching:

```
fail 'bang' rescue 5
# => 5

'bang' rescue 5
# => "bang"

nil rescue 5
# => nil
```

In your examples, given that `A` do not respond to `value`:

```
A.value
# NoMethodError: undefined method `value' ...

b = A.value || 5
# NoMethodError: ...
b
# => nil

b = A.value rescue 5
b
# => 5
```

Now suppose that `A.value` returns `nil`:

```
A.value
# => nil

b = A.value || 5
b
# => 5

b = A.value rescue 5
b
# => nil
```

Comment: is it good that A.value always return nil instead of no method found?

Answer (score 8):

The `||` is an `or` operator. Your first line reads:

Set b to A.value; if not b (i.e. b is nil or false), then set it to the string "5".

Rescue lets you recover from exceptions. Your second line reads:

Set b to A.value. If A.value raises an exception, ignore the problem and set b to 5 instead.

For an object A with no value method, the first line will crash the app.

For an object A whose value method returns nil, the second line will set b to nil.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what others already told you, one more difference is, that `||` is an honest operator, while inline `rescue` is tantamount to rescuing `StandardError`, which is someting that [various manuals of style passionately frown upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173). In other words, inline `rescue` is an indecent hack, that should not be used too frequently in production code. Use decently dressed `begin ... rescue ... else ... ensure ... end` statement instead.