# Is this an acceptable use of Rails controllers along with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Is there a better way of having ajax return real-time data than creating a controller for this task and calling to it via $.ajax every so often?

For example, to fetch data from Redis, I've a controller with methods along the lines of

```
def get_size
 begin
  render :text => JSON.generate({:data => redis_instance.get("some_key"})
 rescue Exception => e
  render :text => JSON.generate({:data => nil})
 end
end
```

Then I have $.ajax call to /get_size. Is this an acceptable practice or are there far better alternatives I don't know about?

Comment: [**Don’t rescue from Exception!**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10048173/211563)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, yes, if you need to get data from your server via `ajax` you'll need to generate your own action in the controller.

The way you manipulate the data could be different, you could do it on the controller (bad bad) or in the client (better better), it depends on the aplication you are building, but using an Javascrip MVC framework it's becoming the standar way to do this. Check [TODO MVC](http://todomvc.com/)

The only thing that might be a little different is, if you need to implement a realtime feature, you could check [`WebSockets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets), and a push server like [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) ( [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub) ) or [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) so you don't have to pull data from rails doing a request ever X seconds.

**EDIT**

Also, I forgot to add that the *Rails way* to do ajax would be using `rails.js` and links with the `remote: true` property, so you can handle the responses with the events the script provides, like `ajax:success` or `ajax:failure`. You can check it out [here](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/).

And, in Rails 4, you can do [`Live Streaming`](http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/08/03/why-rails-4-live-streaming-is-a-big-deal/) for realtime.