# how to use retry and rescue exception using ruby and watir in right way?

Tags: ruby, watir

```
begin
  ie.select_list(:id, "PageSize").select_value("300")
rescue Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException  
  aftererrorObj.errorMain(ie,con,country)
  retry
rescue Timeout::Error
  aftererrorObj.errorMain(ie,con,country)
  retry 
end
```

**my ruby code is handling exception in this way.Is this right way to handle exception? will it work?**

Comment: Why are you retrying in the event of an exception? Will something change that will change the action from failing to working? For example, if the element is loaded via ajax, rescuing/retrying the timeout might work. However, you should really design the script to expect it by using one of the wait methods.

Comment: but I want to know, can I rescue these exception using one rescue ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to rescue the script in case the object has not loaded yet due to AJAX or slow response time, something like this might be more appropriate:

```
Watir::Wait.until(60) { ie.select_list(:id, "PageSize").exists? }
```

OR

```
ie.select_list(:id, "PageSize").when_present.select_value("300)
```

Comment: @thanks adam , but I want to know, can I rescue these exception using one rescue ?

Answer (score 0):

If just want to catch multiple types of exceptions in the same rescue, combine them as comma separated list:

```
begin
  ie.select_list(:id, "PageSize").select_value("300")
rescue Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException, Timeout::Error
  aftererrorObj.errorMain(ie,con,country)
  retry
end
```

Comment: can I do it like that "rescue Exception"as it is super class of all exceptions

Comment: Yes, you can. However, it is not recommended - see this [other question for an explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby).