# How get the error of ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
  begin

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do

      // ...
      sanitized_sql = "INSERT INTO pinfo ..."
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sanitized_sql)

    end

  rescue

    // how can I get the error?       

  end
```

In the webrick console, the error (`1967-07-16?00:00:00`) is shown as:

> EXECUTE (0.0ms)   ODBC::Error: 22008 (241) [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Syntax error converting datetime from character string.: INSERT INTO pinfo (birthdate) VALUES ('1967-07-16?00:00:00')
>   EXECUTE (0.8ms)   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

How can I get the above error message (`ODBC::Error: 22008 (241) ...`) raised from `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` in `rescue`?

Comment: did you try `rescue ODBC::Error` thanks

Comment: I'd like to catch all errors, not specific ones. What I need is the error message generated in the exception.

Comment: `rescue Exception => exc    
   logger.error("Message for the log file #{exc.message}")    
   flash[:notice] = "Store error message #{exec.message}"    
  
end  `

Comment: Thanks Rajarshi. Could you please move the comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 begin  
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do  

  // ...
  sanitized_sql = "INSERT INTO pinfo ..."
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sanitized_sql)

  end
 rescue Exception => exc 
   logger.error("Message for the log file #{exc.message}") 
   flash[:notice] = "Store error message #{exec.message}" 
 end
```

Thanks

Comment: Consider changing it to rescue StandardException - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby