# How to handle 404 not found errors in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, http-status-code-404, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to scrape web pages. Few urls need to be guessed and returns 404 not found error when they don't exist. Is there a way to capture this exception?

```
http://yoursite/page/38475 #=> page number 38475 doesn't exist
```

I tried the following which didn't work.

```
url = "http://yoursite/page/38475"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)) do
  begin
    rescue Exception => e
      puts "Try again later"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It doesn't work, because you are not rescuing part of code (it's `open(url)` call) that raises an error in case of finding 404 status. The following code should work:

```
url = 'http://yoursite/page/38475'
begin
  file = open(url)
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(file) do
    # handle doc
  end
rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => e
  if e.message == '404 Not Found'
    # handle 404 error
  else
    raise e
  end
end
```

BTW, about rescuing `Exception`:
[Why is it a bad style to `rescue Exception => e` in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby)

Comment: I thing is better to use `e.io.not_found?`