# How to handle 500 Internal Server Error and 404 Page Not Found with Anemone, Boilerpipe and Nokigiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, http-error, anemone

I'm implementing a tool that needs to crawl a website. I'm using anemone to crawl and on each anemone's page I'm using boilerpipe and Nokogiri to manage HTML format, etc.

My problem is: if I get 500 Internal Server Error, it makes Nokogiri fail because there is no page.

```
Anemone.crawl(name) do |anemone|
   anemone.on_every_page do |page|
       if not (page.nil? && page.not_found?)
              result = Boilerpipe.extract(page.url, {:output => :htmlFragment, :extractor => :ArticleExtractor})
              doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(result)

       end
    end
end
```

In the case above, if there is a 500 Internal Server Error, the application will give an error on Nokogiri::HTML.parse(). I want to avoid this problem. If the server gives an error I want to continue computation ignoring this page.

There is any way to handle 500 Internal Server Error and 404 Page Not Found with these tools?

Kind regards,
Hugo

Comment: Ok, I think I found the solution. Each anemone page has a field called code. This code represents server's response.

Answer (score 5):

```
# gets the reponse of the link
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))

# if it returns a good code
if res.code.to_i >= 200 && res.code.to_i < 400 #good codes will be betweem 200 - 399
  # do something with the url
else
  # skip the object
  next
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much TheChamp, I find right now that anemone's page has a field called code.

Comment: Ok, glad to hear, if you want to, you can try my solution and tell me if it worked aswell!

Comment: It works too but there is a problem: when anemone performs the request action it could receive 500 Internal Server Error and then when you execute your code it could give a good reply.

Comment: There shouldn't be that possibility, could you post a url to such a site or further explain the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. The question and the reply is here

[How to handle 404 errors with Nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270596/how-to-handle-404-not-found-errors-in-nokogiri)

Comment: Ok, I think I found the solution. Each anemone page has a field called code. This code represents server's response.