# Ruby equivalent for Python's "try"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ruby, try-catch, language-comparisons

I'm trying to convert some Python code into Ruby. Is there an equivalent in Ruby to the `try` statement in Python?

Comment: show one code please!

Comment: Look up Ruby `rescue` (and `raise`)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Use this as an example:

```
begin  # "try" block
    puts 'I am before the raise.'  
    raise 'An error has occurred.' # optionally: `raise Exception, "message"`
    puts 'I am after the raise.'   # won't be executed
rescue # optionally: `rescue StandardError => ex`
    puts 'I am rescued.'
ensure # will always get executed
    puts 'Always gets executed.'
end
```

The equivalent code in Python would be:

```
try:     # try block
    print('I am before the raise.')
    raise Exception('An error has occurred.') # throw an exception
    print('I am after the raise.')            # won't be executed
except:  # optionally: `except Exception as ex:`
    print('I am rescued.')
finally: # will always get executed
    print('Always gets executed.')
```

Comment: There's also the quirky `else` clause that gets executed only if no exceptions have been triggered.

Comment: this is most easieast answer and understandable, thanks thanks

Comment: one of the best answers on SO from both a form and content perspective; much thanks

Comment: It's better to rescue `StandardError` instead of `Exception` (as in the comment in the Ruby example): https://stackoverflow.com/q/10048173/12484

Answer (score 13):

```
 begin
     some_code
 rescue
      handle_error  
 ensure 
     this_code_is_always_executed
 end
```

Details: http://crodrigues.com/try-catch-finally-equivalent-in-ruby/

Comment: Great link! It's really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to catch a particular type of exception, use:

```
begin
    # Code
rescue ErrorClass
    # Handle Error
ensure
    # Optional block for code that is always executed
end
```

This approach is preferable to a bare "rescue" block as "rescue" with no arguments will catch a StandardError or any child class thereof, including NameError and TypeError.

Here is an example:

```
begin
    raise "Error"
rescue RuntimeError
    puts "Runtime error encountered and rescued."
end
```