# Can I automatically re-run a method if a timeout error occurs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have an application that makes hundreds of API calls to external services. Sometimes some calls take too much time to respond.

I am using the [rake_timeout](https://github.com/kch/rack-timeout) gem to find time consuming process, so, `Timeout::Error` will be thrown whenever some request is taking too long to respond. I am rescuing this error and doing a retry on that method:

```
def new
 @make_one_external_service_call = exteral_api_fetch1(params[:id])
 @make_second_external_call = exteral_api_fetch1(@make_one_external_service_call)

  #Below code will be repeated in every method

 tries = 0
rescue Timeout::Error => e
  tries += 1
  retry if tries <= 3
  logger.error e.message 
end
```

This lets the method fully re-run it. This is very verbose and I am repeating it every time.

Is there any way to do this so that, if the `Timeout:Error` occurrs, it will retry that method automatically three times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a little module for that:

```
# in lib/retryable.rb
module Retryable

  # Options:
  # * :tries - Number of tries to perform. Defaults to 1. If you want to retry once you must set tries to 2.
  # * :on - The Exception on which a retry will be performed. Defaults to Exception, which retries on any Exception.
  # * :log - The log level to log the exception. Defaults to nil.
  #
  # If you work with something like ActiveRecord#find_or_create_by_foo, remember to put that call in a uncached { } block. That
  # forces subsequent finds to hit the database again.
  #
  # Example
  # =======
  #   retryable(:tries => 2, :on => OpenURI::HTTPError) do
  #     # your code here
  #   end
  #
  def retryable(options = {}, &block)
    opts = { :tries => 1, :on => Exception }.merge(options)

    retry_exception, retries = opts[:on], opts[:tries]

    begin
      return yield
    rescue retry_exception => e
      logger.send(opts[:log], e.message) if opts[:log]
      retry if (retries -= 1) > 0
    end

    yield
  end

end
```

and than in your model:

```
extend Retryable

def new
  retryable(:tries => 3, :on => Timeout::Error, :log =>:error) do
    @make_one_external_service_call = exteral_api_fetch1(params[:id])
    @make_second_external_call = exteral_api_fetch1(@make_one_external_service_call)
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: This is a fantastic start. There are a few issues though. First, it will run `tries` + 1 times. Also, you should never rescue from `Exception` but instead the default should be to rescue from `StandardError` (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10048406/1084109)

Here's an updated version: https://gist.github.com/mcfadden/0130f1a7fe52463b6628

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
module Foo
  def self.retryable(options = {})
    retry_times   = options[:times] || 10
    try_exception = options[:on]    || Exception

    yield if block_given?
  rescue *try_exception => e
    retry if (retry_times -= 1) > 0
    raise e
  end
end

Foo.retryable(on: Timeout::Error, times: 5) do
  # your code here
end
```

You can even pass multiple exceptions to "catch":

```
Foo.retryable(on: [Timeout::Error, StandardError]) do
  # your code here
end
```

Comment: Thanks, all answers are good and perfect but I only have to choose one. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is the [retryable](https://github.com/robertsosinski/retryable) gem.

With the gem, you can write your method like below

```
def new
  retryable :on => Timeout::Error, :times => 3 do
   @make_one_external_service_call = exteral_api_fetch1(params[:id])
   @make_second_external_call = exteral_api_fetch1(@make_one_external_service_call)
  end
end
```

Please read the documentation for more information on how to use the gem and the other options it provides

Comment: Thanks, all answers are good and perfect but I only have to choose one. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you could just write a helper-method for that:

```
class TimeoutHelper
  def call_and_retry(tries=3)
    yield
  rescue Timeout::Error => e
    tries -= 1
    retry if tries > 0
    Rails.logger.error e.message
  end
end
```

(completely untested) and call it via

```
TimeoutHelper.call_and_retry { [your code] }
```

Comment: Thanks, all answers are good and perfect but I only have to choose one. Sorry.