# How to continue with the next rescue block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, actionmailer, rescue

In my Rails 3.2.15 / Ruby 1.9.3p448 project I want to catch exceptions produced by [ActionMailer](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actionmailer) ...

```
begin
  if message.deliver
    render json: { message: "Message sent successfully" }, status: 201
  else
    render json: { error: "Failure sending message" }, status: 401
  end
rescue ArgumentError => e
  if e.message == "An SMTP To address is required to send a message."
    render json: { error: "Invalid recipient address" }, status: 422
  else
    # Continue with generic exception
  end
rescue Exception => e
  render json: { error: e.message }, status: 500
end
```

In case of an `ArgumentError` I want to implement two different behaviors:

1. If the message matches a specific error message I want to render a custom response.
2. In other cases I want to continue and let the generic exception block rescue from the error.

Comment: `raise "The exception with the message"` in the else block, so that generic exception can catch

Comment: @AbibullahRahamathulah Sorry, this does not work. I cannot reach the second rescue block this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it. Please also do not rescue from `Exception` [for the reasons detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby) – use `StandardError` instead.

```
begin
  if message.deliver
    render json: { message: "Message sent successfully" }, status: 201
  else
    render json: { error: "Failure sending message" }, status: 401
  end
rescue StandardError => e
  if e.is_a?(ArgumentError) && e.message == "An SMTP To address is required to send a message."
    render json: { error: "Invalid recipient address" }, status: 422
  else
    render json: { error: e.message }, status: 500
  end
end
```

Comment: It crashes with `TypeError - class or module required:` here `if e.is_a? ArgumentError && ..`

Comment: Works for me here on MRI 2.0.0p247. Which ruby version are you using?

Comment: Looks like a bug in 1.9.3 to me? What do you think?

Comment: I think I might have made one of those copy-paste or refactoring-without-running-again mistakes. Now I can reproduce the error on 2.0, so my code was actually incorrect. Sorry for the confusion!