# Ruby Retry and ensure block is not working

Tags: ruby

In the code below retry and ensure block is not working when there is an error.

```
def doCalc
    begin
        print( "Enter a number: " )
        aNum = gets().chomp()
        result = 100 / aNum.to_i
    rescue Exception => e       
        result = 0
        puts( "Error: " + e + "\nPlease try again." )
        retry   # retry on exception
    else
        msg = "Result = #{result}"
    ensure
        msg = "You entered '#{aNum}'. " + msg
    end
    return msg
end


puts( doCalc )
```

Please let me know what is the problem here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about the previous suggestion. I've just noticed the actual cause of error. The following works as you'd assume it to:

```
def doCalc
  begin
    print( "Enter a number: " )
    aNum = gets().chomp()
    result = 100 / aNum.to_i
  #rescue Exception => e    # - dont catch Exception unless you REALLY need it.
  rescue => e               # - this catches StandardError and is usually enough
    result = 0
    puts( "Error: #{e}\nPlease try again." )   # <-- changed here
    retry   # retry on exception
  else
    msg = "Result = #{result}"
  ensure
    msg = "You entered '#{aNum}'. " + msg
  end
  return msg
end
```

You've actually had THREE errors thrown one after another.

First error ocurred as you planned - during the parsing and division. And it was caught by the `rescue Exception => e` properly.

But you cannot "add" an "exception" to a "string". Trying to `"asd" + e + "asd"` caused another error to be thrown what crashed your 'rescue' block. However, the immediatelly following 'ensure' block **must run**, so while your rescue block was about to quit and rise another error, the `ensure` block fired.

And the `ensure` block failed to add `msg` to the string, since `msg` was `nil` at the moment. So, for the third time an exception was raised, and it successfully has hidden all the previous exceptions.

In short: Note how I now replaced the add-exception-to-a-string with string interpolation. You cannot add `e` directly. You have to either use interpolation, or call `e.to_s` manually.

Comment: But I was reading "Book of ruby" and everywhere it uses this type of code and most of them are not working. What is the problem here? I mean the book says it should be an exception and they also showed the answer

Comment: I was still editing the post. Please read it now. The `rescue` and `ensure` are working properly. You have failed at string-concatenation.