# Exceptions in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

simple `index` action in my app

```
 def index
  @reports = CustomReport.all
 end
```

when the application was to ready I was told to add `exceptions`, I copied it from other `application` as I did not have any idea,

```
def index
    begin
      @reports = CustomReport.all
    rescue Exception => e
      Rails.logger.info "Exception in design_custom_reports controller, index action"
      Rails.logger.info e
      flash[:notice] = "Sorry, something went wrong. Please inform administration"
      redirect_to :controller => :user, :action => :dashboard
    end
end
```

and now it looks clumsy isn't it?

Best way to handle the scenario in `RoR`?

Comment: I don't understand the idea of this exception handler, what do you want to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby

Comment: I really doesn't make sense. You try to catch an error while requesting all records from database? Usually the application will stop working before running into this rescue

Comment: This is just a side point, but instead of def...begin...rescue...end the generally accepted style is to def...rescue...end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer

That rescue clause doesn't really make sense. Remove it.

### Long answer

That's a very bad code. First of all, the question is: who told you to "add exceptions" and for which purpose?

The code

```
CustomReport.all
```

is known to raise an exception only in very special cases. Generally speaking, when the application can't connect to the database. In fact, there are no external user inputs or conditions that may cause the code to naturally fail.

Conversely, this code can fail more frequently

```
CustomReport.find(params[:id])
```

because find raises an error if the object is not found, which is definitely a more common case.

If your method crashes for a database error, it's likely the entire application is affected so the rescue management probably makes sense in your global application, not really in that method. There's not that much you can do there to rescue it.

Last but not least, rescuing an exception of class Exception

```
rescue Exception => e
```

is considered a code smell in Ruby. In fact, you should rescue only StandardErrors or greater.  If you rescue an `Exception` class you must be very aware of what it means. System level errors and syntax errors inherits from Exception, so if you rescue an `Exception` it's likely that you will hide a lot of potential errors in your code.

But again, even rescuing `StandardError` does not make a lot of sense. In fact, we said before that `CustomReport.all` could only fail in case of database connection errors. This means that, if you really want to rescue something, you should rescue only database failures there.

Comment: The final work is that in the case you mentioned, the exception management you wrote does not make sense. Whenever you are writing code, you should have corresponding unit/functional/integration tests. If you write the tests for the code you wrote, you will notice on your own that the way you wrote it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: [Don’t rescue Exception. EVER. or I will stab you.](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#general-tips)

Answer (score 0):

you can put that code in Application controller . and it will capture all error in your whole application. and you do not need to write any more thing in any other controller  as they are already inherited by application controller

```
rescue_from Exception  do |exception|
  @error = exception
  exception_logger
end

private

def exception_logger
 Rails.logger.error "Exception in design_custom_reports controller, index action"
 Rails.logger.error @error
 flash[:notice] = "Sorry, something went wrong. Please inform administration"
 redirect_to :controller => :user, :action => :dashboard
end
```

Comment: That's a very bad example. Never rescue an exception of type `Exception` (this is a common Java practice that is considered bad code in Ruby), especially in a complex application such as Rails.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti i know that but i just try to give a solution according to question :(

Comment: I understand. However, given the level of expertise of the user, I think it's more effective to provide a solution that would not encourage him to follow bad practices. ;)

Comment: @SimoneCarletti i will keep that in mind in my future answer . thanks for your suggestion