# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG InFailedSqlTransaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rollback, pg

I am trying to create an ActiveRecord Object.But I'm getting this error while creating it.

```
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is       aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Any ideas folks regarding the issue.

Comment: Are you using PSQL with a column type of `json`? Update it to PSQL 9.4 and use `jsonb`. Problem solved!

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html
this is the main issue, we had.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

None of the other answers fix the ***root cause*** of the issue.

The problem is that when Postgres raises an exception, it poisons future  transactions on the same connection.

The fix is to rollback the offending transaction:

```
begin
  ActiveRecord...do something...
rescue Exception => e
  puts "SQL error in #{ __method__ }"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'ROLLBACK'

  raise e
end
```

See [reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-rollback.html).

Comment: Also mentioned in the Rails [AR::Transactions manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Transactions::ClassMethods-label-Exception+handling+and+rolling+back)

Comment: Please don't rescue from `Exception`, as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby

    Exception is the root of Ruby's exception hierarchy, so when you rescue Exception you rescue from everything, including subclasses such as SyntaxError, LoadError, and Interrupt.

Comment: @adantj It is perfectly fine to rescue Exception **when you immediately re-raise**; as is done in the given answer

Comment: Rollback using `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback` helped me. Also for reference https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Comment: This feels like a bandage that will hide the true root cause. The real solution is to identify the exception and fix it

Answer (score 87):

I had this issue. Just restart the Rails Server and it should work

Comment: I just had this issue and restarting the server did fix it, in fact. Does somebody have an explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: I had the same issue on test environment (rspec throws the error). `rake db:drop` + `rake db:create` + `rake db:migrate` solved the issue. Maybe I messed up with migration.

Comment: Was testing in rails console. Reloading was not sufficient, needed to restart the console. Thanks!

Comment: This is not a viable solution, restarting a server isn't an option when a service is supposed to be running autonomously.  The issue is that the PG connection is in a bad state and needs to be reconnected or needs to execute `ROLLBACK` to exit the current transaction.

Comment: This occurred to me after upgrading to PG12 and Ruby 2.6.6. I use rvm and the upgrade to 2.6.6 required a rebuild of the pg gem for the new gemset. A `rake db:test:prepare` did not work -- but a `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` solved the problem.

Comment: Concurring on the comments to reset the db. Once I did rake db:drop + rake db:create + rake db:migrate, solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 17):

This issue was occurring in my test environment, and was caused by the fact that each test was wrapped in its own transaction.

I was using the database_cleaner gem, and have it configured so as NOT to wrap tests in a transaction if they use javascript. So to solve the issue, I added `js: true` to each spec that was causing this problem.  (Even thought the specs did not actually use javascript, this was the most convenient way to ensure that the tests would not be wrapped in a transaction.  I am sure there are less hack-ish ways of doing so, though).

For reference, here is the database_cleaner config from `spec/support/database_cleaner.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :deletion
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :deletion
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

If you are not using database_cleaner, then probably the reason the tests would be wrapped in transactions would be that the `use_transactional_fixtures` option is set to `true` in `spec/spec_helper.rb`. Try setting it to false.

Comment: If you disable transactional fixtures without plugging in something like DatabaseCleaner, then your test database will continue to pile up data from each run. Rather than setting `js: true` for each spec that doesn't work as expected, you can set it for integration specs. Keep in mind that using `:deletion` instead of `:transaction` is much slower, so transactions are preferable where feasible.

Comment: To this point, I found the added complexity of DB cleaners as opposed to default transactional tests was tough (aka more errors popping up).  But my issue was that I had two requests like `get ...` in the same `it` block.  Moving it out fixed this error.

Comment: I don't think adding `js: true` is the best way to fix this issue. It does not solve the problem and deletion strategy is **very slow**. I sped up my tests by a factor of 2.5x by switching to transaction strategy. See my answer below.

Comment: This worked for me and allowed me to identify the actual issue. Once it was resolved I set use_transactional_fixtures back to true and others probably should too

Answer (score 8):

you can see what really going on in postgresql log, I spend a lot of time to dig into this issue, and finally find out that we misuse upsert gem cause a PG error, only in postgresql log have the real info of what's going on

https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert/issues/39

Comment: The link didn't help much but the idea of checking the postgres logs totally did. In my case it was an unprepared test database. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I've run into this error when referencing a column in my specs that no longer exists. Make sure your database is up to date and your code doesn't expect a column that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Problem:

1. The program executes incorrect SQL statement. Incorrect SQL statement is root cause of the problem.
2. The program does not ROLLBACK or RELEASE SAVEPOINT immediately after incorrect SQL statement.
3. The program executes SQL statements after incorrect SQL statement.
4. PostgreSQL raises ERROR: Current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Solution:

Find incorrect SQL statement and correct it.
If you don't want to correct the SQL statement, use ROLLBACK or RELEASE SAVEPOINT after incorrect SQL statement.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the Postgres configuration at `/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf` had the datetype as the international format of `dmy`

Changing datetype to the American format of `mdy` fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I received this error simply because I had not rake'd my test db.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem after upgrading Rails from 4.2.2 to 4.2.5 I had to upgrade `pg` gem and problem start happening

```
9) WorkPolicy#is_publicly_viewable? is publicly visible hides work if deleted
     Failure/Error: before { DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :deletion }
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
       :             SELECT tablename
                   FROM pg_tables
                   WHERE schemaname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
```

[Teddy Widom Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22383251/473040)  is right in this sense, just to sum the problem:

Sometimes when you use `DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :deletion` you may be interfering  PostgreSQL transaction.

So solution for me was to replace `DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :deletion` in parts of the tests where this was caused  with `DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation`

Just one more thing for googling people. If you are noticing this stack trace:

```
An error occurred in an `after(:context)` hook.
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "table_rows" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ion_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'test' AND table_rows...
^
```

...it may be caused by this problem

Answer (score 0):

I got that problem. 
And I found out that it was my query.
It mean when I query with association without specifying a table column.
ex:

```
class Holiday < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :timeoffs
end
```

In Holiday model I query

```
company.timeoffs.where("(start_date <= ? and end_date >= ?) and id != ?", begin_date, begin_date, 1)
```

The error occurs because I didn't specify which table's `id` 
It worked for me after I changed the code to

```
company.timeoffs.where("(start_date <= ? and end_date >= ?) and time_offs.id != ?", begin_date, begin_date, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this, I ran

```
tail -f /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log
```

Then it is just a matter of replicating the error and watching the output in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Run this two command on your terminal:

```bash
$ rm /opt/homebrew/var/postgres/postmaster.pid  # (Here maybe have different path)
$ brew services restart postgresql
```

This is working from my side.