# `Event.where("start_time >= ?", DateTime.now)` does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm adding support for recurring events to my Rails app.
One of the functions is `recurring_event.delete_this_and_following`

**app/models/recurring_event.rb**

```
   16 class RecurringEvent < ApplicationRecord
   17   belongs_to :event

   32   def delete_this_and_following
   33     event.recurring_events.where("start_time >= ?", start_time).destroy_all
   34   end
```

Unfortunately this gives me this error:

```
(byebug) event.recurring_events.where("start_time >= ?", start_time).size
*** ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: 
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end 
of transaction block
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "recurring_events" 
WHERE "recurring_events"."event_id" = $1 AND 
(start_time >= '2018-10-23 10:42:50.281315')

nil
```

Has start_date wrong format? `start_time.to_s => "2018-10-23 11:24:59 UTC"`

Comment: What is the value of `start_time`? And what is the datatype `start_time` column?

Comment: start_time =>
Tue, 23 Oct 2018 11:24:59 UTC +00:00

Comment: ` t.datetime "start_time"`

Comment: try `event.recurring_events.where("recurring_events.start_time >= ?", start_time).destroy_all`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138207/activerecordstatementinvalid-pg-infailedsqltransaction

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. It might have been spring that failed to reload or something.
I did a reboot of my machine today and now this works:

```
event.recurring_events.where("start_time >= ?", start_time).destroy_all
```

Thanks for the suggestions anyway! :-)