# Rescue Exception to overcome gem error?

Tags: ruby, exception, rubygems, pusher, ruby-2.1

I am trying to use the pusher-client gem to receive a Pusher from a website (near real-time data). However, the script tends to die a lot.

If I post the Pusher data to my screen, then the client runs for as long as I care to let it run. However, if I save the Pusher data to a file, or pass the data to a Gearman job, using the gearman gem, or put the data into Memcache, using the dalli gem, then my client script crashes.

My server is not overloaded in any way. It has 8 cores and 24 GB of RAM. Typically no single core is at 100% and no more than 6 are in use at any time and no more than 12 GB of the RAM is ever in use.

My current incarnation of the client script is attempting to pass the data off to a Gearman job, and I hope that this will offload the saving of the data and prevent missing any updates provided by Pusher, which can often come very quickly. This is a representative error the script kicks out:

```
ruby-2.1.1/gems/gearman-ruby-3.0.7/lib/gearman/taskset.rb:99:in `handle_job_created': Got unexpected job_created notification with handle H:hawk898
        from /home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/gearman-ruby-3.0.7/lib/gearman/taskset.rb:222:in `read_packet'
        from /home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/gearman-ruby-3.0.7/lib/gearman/taskset.rb:67:in `add_task_internal'
        from /home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/gearman-ruby-3.0.7/lib/gearman/taskset.rb:29:in `add_task'
        from /var/www/.../utils/pusher_utils.rb:81:in `send_to_gearman'
        from /var/www/.../utils/pusher_utils.rb:10:in `export_to_gearman'
        from /var/www/.../async_pusher.rb:59:in `block in <main>'
        from /home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/pusher-client-0.4.0/lib/pusher-client/channel.rb:30:in `call'
        from /home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/pusher-client-0.4.0/lib/pusher-client/channel.rb:30:in `block in dispatch'
        from /home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/pusher-client-0.4.0/lib/pusher-client/channel.rb:29:in `each'
        from /home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/pusher-client-0.4.0/lib/pusher-client/channel.rb:29:in `dispatch'
        from /home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/pusher-client-0.4.0/lib/pusher-client/channel.rb:22:in `dispatch_with_all'
        from /home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/pusher-client-0.4.0/lib/pusher-client/socket.rb:201:in `send_local_event'
        from /home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/pusher-client-0.4.0/lib/pusher-client/socket.rb:73:in `block (2 levels) in connect'
        from /home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/pusher-client-0.4.0/lib/pusher-client/socket.rb:67:in `loop'
        from /home/gabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/pusher-client-0.4.0/lib/pusher-client/socket.rb:67:in `block in connect'
```

I don't want to dig into the pusher-client gem and figure out why this is happening. I simply want to move on, so I'm tempted to use `rescue Exception`. I am saving the data provided by Pusher for downstream logic and action. The data is fast moving and I can either determine if the job actually made it to Gearman, possibly missing the next update or delaying it, or I can simply mark the currently stored data as stale/invalid and wait for the next update from Pusher. My preference is to mark it as stale/invalid and wait.

I've read "[Why is it a bad style to `rescue Exception => e` in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby)" and know that `rescue Exception` is bad practice. However, I'm not doing this to cover up a bug in my code - I've looked at the workloads being passed to Gearman at the time of the error and they are fine.

I'm running:

```
Ubuntu 12.04
RVM and Ruby 2.1.1
```

Here is some sample code that sends a heartbeat workload to the Gearman job server:

```
def heartbeat(site, marketId, taskset)
    startTime = timeID()

    workload = myhash()
    workload['marketId'] = marketId
    workload['site'] = site
    workload['src'] = 'pusher'
    workload['time'] = startTime
    workload['staleTime'] = startTime + 1

    send_to_gearman('update_heartbeat', json_encode(workload), taskset)

    endTime = timeID()
    delta =endTime - startTime
    puts sprintf("Heartbeat Task Handoff took: %9.4f msec", delta * 1E3)
end # def heartbeat

def send_to_gearman(wrkr, workload, taskset)
    pp workload

    begin
        task = Gearman::Task.new(wrkr, workload, { :priority => :high, :background => true })
        taskset.add_task(task)
        taskset.wait
    rescue => e
        pp e
    end # begin
end # def send_to_gearman
```

The entirety of the code runs fine for minutes if not hours before failing. Specifically every line of code is being exercised repeatedly, except those after `rescue`, without failing prior to the `handle_job_created` error.

So, is it safe to use `rescue Exception` in this case? Is there some subset of Exception I could use instead that I'm missing? Any better suggestions or gotchas I may have overlooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only rescue the errors that are actually raised.  In this case `Gearman::ProtocolError` is the [error being raised](https://github.com/gearman-ruby/gearman-ruby/blob/master/lib/gearman/taskset.rb#L99).  So use:

```
rescue Gearman::ProtocolError
```

Comment: That seems like a better solution. I want to test it before marking it as the answer. How did you determine it was Gearman::ProtocolError? I don't see that in the error lines I provided. Did I miss something?

Comment: @gabe, I linked to the line on github in my answer.  Here is where its raised https://github.com/gearman-ruby/gearman-ruby/blob/master/lib/gearman/taskset.rb#L99 and here is the error class definition https://github.com/gearman-ruby/gearman-ruby/blob/master/lib/gearman.rb#L70-L71

Comment: My pusher client script has run for over 12 hrs now. That's better than any other time I've run it. I wanted to know how you figured out what the error was so I could find it myself in the future. Thanks