# How to programatically get rspec output error backtrace

Tags: rspec, rspec2

I have a ruby script which needs to execute rspec tests and collect results.
I'm using standard rspec API to achieve this:

```
require 'rspec'
require 'rspec/core'
require 'rspec/core/formatters/json_formatter'
require 'json'

def run_test(test_location)
 config = RSpec.configuration
 json_formatter = RSpec::Core::Formatters::JsonFormatter.new(config.output)
 reporter =  RSpec::Core::Reporter.new(json_formatter)
 config.instance_variable_set(:@reporter, reporter)
 begin
  ::RSpec::Core::Runner.run([test_location,'--format','j'])
  json_formatter.output_hash
 rescue Exception => e
  e.message
 end
end

run_test(<PATH_TO_RSPEC_TEST_SCRIPT>)
```

Now, when something fails in rspec test, I can only get error message but I would like to get backtrace from the underlying rspec test that failed. Is there a way to achieve this?
I've tried passing arguments: --backtrace or -b to the array that is passed to RSpec::Core::Runner.run method but didn't get much of the help with that

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The backtrace for any example that raises an exception is available in the `RSpec::Core::Formatters::JsonFormatter` instance. There is no need to add the `-b` option to the arguments.

```
json_formatter.examples.each do |example|
    printf( "Example:  [%s]\n", example.metadata[:description] )
    printf( "Backtrace:\n %s\n", example.exception.backtrace.join("\n ") ) unless example.exception.nil?
end
```

An [Exception](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Exception.html#method-i-backtrace) will include a backtrace as well

```
rescue Exception => e
  warn e.message
  e.backtrace
end
```

Be careful when using `rescue Exception` as [you will catch more than you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10048406/1318694).

Comment: Thanks but I think this works only when some spec test fails and we need to get backtrace. On the other hand, if someone makes syntactical error like for example do following:

    desscribe "test" do
 it "doesn't work" do
  1.should eq(1)
 end
    end



json_formatter_object contains:
#<RSpec::Core::Formatters::JsonFormatter:0x007ffcf40f1858 @output=#  <StringIO:0x007ffcf40f1830>, @failure_count=0, @pending_count=0, @example_count=0, @examples=[], @failed_examples=[], @pending_examples=[], @example_group=nil, @output_hash={}>

Comment: On the other hand, if we run this same spec file from cmd, we will get this:
/Users/bjusufbe/Desktop/rspec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `desscribe' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

What I need is handle these cases as well and retrieve line of the code where this error happens (same we have in cmd line execution)

Comment: `rspec` does not catch exceptions at that level so it exits with the backtrace.  The `JsonFormatter` remains in it's initial state when an exception occurs as you were catching all exceptions and returning the exception message.

Comment: Your other option is to not delve into the internals of Rspec. You can run `rspec` via `system`. Check the exit status and pull the results from file (`--format json --out rspec.json `) or `stderr` for when rspec fails.