# Rails JSON API tests don't return json when exception is thrown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, rspec

I'm writing a test to check for invalid DELETE requests to a Rails API using Rspec.

This is what I have:

```
context 'invalid id number' do
  it 'returns success: false' do
      xhr :delete, :destroy, id: 999999999999999999
      expect(JSON.parse(response.body)['success']).to be_false
  end
end
```

Postgres throws some kind of integer overflow exception (as it should), but in my spec I can't look at the JSON object because it's never formed. How can I make it return { success : false } instead of a blank string? How do I force the JSON object to return despite the exception?

When I use pry to look at the json object, I get this error: `JSON::ParserError: A JSON text must at least contain two octets!` because response.body evaluates to the empty string `""`

Whoa, almost forgot to include the controller code.

```
def destroy
  if (site == ::MyModel.find(params[:id]))
    site.destroy
    render :json => {success: true}
  else
    render :json => {success: false} 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. Depending on your database an id of "999999999999999999" is probably outside of an integer type. I recommend reducing it to below signed integer limit, like 9999.
2. You are trying to find a non-existent record and its raising a record_not_found exception.  I recommend changing your destroy method to:

---

```
def destroy
  site = ::MyModel.find_by(id:params[:id])
  if (site.present?)
    render :json => {success: false} 
  else
    site.first.destroy
    render :json => {success: true}
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

@rafb3 is correct `find_by` and `present?` is a better choice.

Comment: you can save a query by using `find_by(id: ...)` and then checking `site.present?`. This way you avoid running the query for `empty?`

Answer (score 1):

By the sounds of it you will need some kind of rescue statement for the exception:

```
rescue ArithmeticException => ex
  # We need to complete the contract and return json here
  @response = { success: false }
end
```

If you want to learn more about contracts check out this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)

Remember to stay away from returning objects in failure responses, as if you send back something like `site` in this case and `site` does not exist or the database connection is not there your exception response code may have its own exception!

Also try and stay away from `rescue Exception => e` explanation here: [Why is it a bad style to `rescue Exception => e` in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby)

TLDR: Your request always expects a json response so in all places even failure it should return one.