# Rails: delete a video object when its youtube source is deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use this code to get info of an youtube video(`youtube_it`gem)

```
  video_info = Video.yt_session.video_by(self.source_id)
  hits = video_info.view_count
  if video_info.rating
    self.rating = video_info.rating.average
    self.likes = video_info.rating.likes.to_i
  end
```

The problem is that sometimes, the original youtube video is deleted, like this: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsZFkiimpKI`. 
So `video_info = Video.yt_session.video_by(self.source_id)` will reports `OpenURI::HTTPError: 404`, and the code cannot continue to get info of next videos.

I want to delete this non-exist video its source is not available anymore, how can I do that? Maybe by `rescue`?

I tried `if Video.yt_session.video_by(self.source_id)`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I’m a bit confused, did you actually try to implement a try rescue block around it?

Comment: @Anti-Fun, no, I don't know how to use `rescue` at all, could you give me an example?

Comment: Ok, will write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the following:

```
begin
  video_info = Video.yt_session.video_by(self.source_id)
  hits = video_info.view_count
  if video_info.rating
    self.rating = video_info.rating.average
    self.likes = video_info.rating.likes.to_i
  end
rescue OpenURI::HTTPError
  # Delete the entry
end
```

Example with multiple cases of catching errors:

```
begin
  # Do the thing
rescue OpenURI::HTTPError
  # Delete the entry
rescue OpenURI::DifferentErrorType
  # Do something different
resuce OpenURI::AnotherType, OpenURI::ASpecialError
  # Do something radically different
end
```

Comment: Can I make it to rescue other errors as well? Sometimes it's other errors, and I want to delete the entry too.

Comment: Yes, but please make sure that you remember that it is bad ruby style to rescue Exception => e, and try to make what you rescue specific. You can read more about this idealogy [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby) I will update my answer to reflect your comment.