# How to access perform parameters in ActiveJob rescue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I am wondering on how do you access ActiveJob perform parameters in the resue block, such as

```
def perform object
end

rescue_from Exception do |e|
   if e.class != ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      **job.arguments.first** 
      # do something
   end
end
```

Thank You !!

Comment: Where is the exception occurring? In the perform method? If so, simply place your rescue block below the culprit code within the perform method. You'll have access to the `object` parameter as a local variable.

Comment: Noz, I have before_enqueue and around_perform as well hence the rescue_from.

Comment: I have not used either of those before, but can you not place your rescue block in either of those blocks? I don't think you want to be using `rescue_from` in your ActiveJob, a simple `rescue ActoveRecord::RecordNotFound => e` should suffice.

Comment: It is definitely supported (and helpful) to use `rescue_from` in ActiveJobs: 
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#exceptions

Specifically, it is very useful in a Job base class (where similar failures can be consolidated to one `rescue_from` rather than copied into a dozen `perform` blocks).

Answer (score 19):

It is possible with `arguments` inside the `rescue_from` block:

```
rescue_from(StandardError) do |exception|
  user = arguments[0]
  post = arguments[1]
  # ...      
end

def perform(user, post)
  # ...
end
```

This also works for callbacks as well (e.g. inside `after_perform`).

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me (Rails 5.0.1, sidekiq 4.2.9). In the `rescue_from` block, `arguments[0]` gave me the first argument that was passed to `perform`.

Answer (score 2):

I had no idea on that as well, then simply decided to try and use `self` inside the `rescue_from` block, and it worked.

```
rescue_from(StandardError) do |ex|
  puts ex.inspect
  puts self.job_id
  # etc.
end
```

As a side note -- NEVER ever rescue `Exception`:

[Why is it a bad style to `rescue Exception => e` in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby)

Comment: rescue_from() only works with exceptions from StandardError down: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28874#issuecomment-297599254

Answer (score 1):

You can access all [Bindings](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html) by `ex.bindings`. To make sure you get the correct binding for your job you should check the receiver like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
method_binding = ex.bindings.find { |b| b.receiver.is_a?(self.class) }
```

Then you can get all local variables with `.local_variable_get`. Since method arguments are also local variables, you can at least explicitly fetch them:

```
user = method_binding.local_variable_get(:user)
post = method_binding.local_variable_get(:post)
```

So for you example:

```
def perform object
end

rescue_from Exception do |e|
   if e.class != ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      method_binding = ex.bindings.find { |b| b.receiver.is_a?(self.class) }
      object = method_binding.local_variable_get(:object)
      # do something
   end
end
```

<sub>1. It is still possible that this binding is not the one of `perform` if you call other instance methods in your job's perform method and the error happens there. This can also be taken in account but is left out for brevity.</sub>