# Rescue nested method call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I read that Ruby doesn't have nested rescues. Is that why this won't work?

```
begin
    dosomething
rescue => e
    #this is never executed, dosomething raises the error directly
end

def dosomething
    SomeModel.find(-1) #this raises the exception instead of above
end
```

Comment: I can't say I understand your question. Are you asking about raising exceptions, or rescuing them?

Comment: I want to rescue dosomething but rescue it above inside the rescue => e. Instead, it just terminates the program directly from dosomething.

Comment: You mean the `rescue` isn't catching the exception?

Comment: When you say "terminates the program directly from dosomething" do you mean you're seeing an exception that's not rescued?

Comment: Yes Steve, the exception caused in dosomething is never rescued in the above code rescue => e

Comment: I can't reproduce this; exceptions should be passed to callers until they are rescued.

Answer (score -1):

Good day.
You must read ruby doc about exceptions
In short:
Exception - base class for All exceptions, therefore base code:

```
begin
  # some code
rescue Exception => e
end
```

You should always specify which exception you handle
If you need proc all - use class Exception

[image]

P.S.
For you self education - http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html

Comment: Are you saying that rescue => e won't ever be executed because it doesn't include the kind of exception to rescue whether it's Exception or something more granular?

Comment: If you don't specify which exception it defaults to StandartError and you probably want to handle StandartError instead of Exception. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby