# Timeout won't reset after the first time out happened

Tags: ruby

I expected that timeout will happen every 30 seconds in the following code:

```
def action_with_timeout(threshould, &block)
  begin
    Timeout::timeout(threshould) {block.call}
  rescue Exception => e
    ap("Timeout #{threshould}, stop loading pag, #{Time.now}")
    stop_loading_page
  end
end
while true
  action_with_timeout(30) {
    ap("to INDEX")
    browse_to(CONFIG["ROOT_URL"])
  }
end
```

However, it only works for the first time. The remaining will timeout in a short time. The output is:

```
"Timeout 30, stop loading pag, 2015-07-01 19:59:10 +0800"
"Timeout 30, stop loading pag, 2015-07-01 19:59:13 +0800"
"Timeout 30, stop loading pag, 2015-07-01 19:59:16 +0800"
"Timeout 30, stop loading pag, 2015-07-01 19:59:19 +0800"
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure the exception is a timeout exception and not something else?

Comment: You should look at what exception it gets by `puts e` before `ap(..)`

Comment: Also if you want to catch only the timeout exception, use `rescue Timeout::Error => e` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rescue Exception` will rescue *any* exception (it's a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10048173/477037) to do so).

Be specific in order to rescue the exception you're interested in:

```
require 'timeout'

def action_with_timeout(sec, &block)
  Timeout::timeout(sec, &block)
rescue Timeout::Error
  # ...
end
```

Other exceptions will not be rescued. This should reveal your actual problem.