# Ruby exception handling in else block

Tags: ruby, logging, error-handling, block, rescue

So I have classic ruby exception handling:

```
begin
    # do work here
rescue SafeShutdown => e
    # prevent loss of data and safely shutdown
rescue SystemExit => e
    # print #{e} and continue
else
    # how can I get #{e} here to get error message
    # so I can behave like in previous rescue
    # 
    # print #{e} and continue
end
```

My question is how can I get "e" to print out in logger in else part of the block.

Comment: How do you suggest getting access to the exception in the `else` clause, which is only executed when there is no exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `begin rescue` block `else` is called only when no exception occurs, i.e. no error was thrown. Try this:

```
begin
  # do work here
rescue SafeShutdown => e
  # print e
rescue SystemExit => e
  # print e
else
  # this will only run when no exceptions are thrown
ensure
  # this will always run
end
```

Comment: I then don't really get function of "else" in there, I though else behaves as a default for any other exception. I had completely misunderstood the else behaviour in that block.

Comment: You could use `rescue Exception => e` to catch all errors, but it's highly unrecommended. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby)