# ruby raise exception on iterator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, nullpointerexception, rubygems

The following function might return a `null` value hence I want to use the exception flow. Can someone direct me to the correct way to do it because right now I am getting the error.

> syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end else

```
def value_from_table1(field, key)
    begin 
      @@connection.query("SELECT #{field} FROM table1 Where key = #{key}  ").each do |row|
        rescue Exception=>e
          puts e
        else 
          return row[field]
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You should escape your query parameters.

Comment: If you take the error flow you should wrap the `row[field]` expression. See e.g. http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/tut_exceptions.html

Comment: why not just make sure to return an enumerable object (that is an object that responds to each) then there is no concern. Also right now if there are multiple rows you will only get the first one which seems wrong too but I am not sure what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a block to `Enumerator#each` which introduces a new scope, so you need to put `begin` as a start of exception block inside.

If you also need handle exceptions of `@@connection.query`, just put `rescue` after `do-end` block of .each. `begin` is implicit at start of method's body.

Answer (score 0):

First, rescuing from Exception is always a bad idea, see [Why is it a bad style to `rescue Exception => e` in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby) for details.

Second a begin rescue block always has to have a closing end, else is only possible after an if before

```
begin
  # ...
rescue StandardError => e 
  # ...
end
```

Third as already said by Justin Turner in the comment, just passing a value to the DB like that makes it prone to SQL injections. Is there any reason you don't use ActiveRecord but want direct DB access?

Overall there are so many issues with this short piece of code, I would suggest to read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ to better understand what is going on.