# What possible reason rescue does not work in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am debugging a problem about `simple_token_authentication`, I modified some code in https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication/blob/master/lib/simple_token_authentication/sign_in_handler.rb#L7 to:

```
def sign_in(controller, record, *args)
  begin
    puts "=== TRACE 1"
    integrate_with_devise_trackable!(controller)
    puts "=== TRACE 2"
    controller.send(:sign_in, record, *args)
    puts "=== TRACE 3"
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "=== TRACE 4"
  ensure
    puts "=== TRACE 5"
  end
end
```

Outputs:

```
Started GET "/projects" for ::1 at 2016-04-18 18:35:22 +0800
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by ProjectsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"project"=>{}}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "testaccount@gmail.com"]]
=== TRACE 1
=== TRACE 2
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
=== TRACE 5
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 40ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

The question isn't about `simple_token_authentication`, the question is why `TRACE 3` and `TRACE 4` both didn't output? Is there a possibly reason could cause th?

My environment:

- ruby-2.2.3 [ x86_64 ] installed by rvm
- Mac OSX 10.11.4

Comment: This is interesting. If only you posted a reproducible snippet... :)

Comment: I try to create a small project to reproduce it.

Comment: Can't reproduce, I just delete db/development.sqlite3 and rake db:migrate, it  outputs TRACE 1, 2, 3 and 5, it's right. I don't know why.

Comment: Don’t rescue Exception.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10048406/1890906

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Devise and warden use [throw/catch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-catch) to communicate that warden was unable to sign the user in. As long as there is a matching `catch` block higher up on the stack, `throw` doesn't raise an exception so the rescue clause isn't called. Ensure is called because it's always supposed to be called. You can test this with this small snippet:

```
def test
  puts "about to throw"
  throw :rock, :hard
rescue Exception => e
  puts "exception: #{e.message}"
ensure
  puts "ensure"
end

result = catch(:rock) { test }
puts result
```

the `rescue` clause won't ever execute, but if you just call `test` on its own then you'll get an `UncaughtThrowException` handled by the block.

In this case, devise provides a rack middleware that catches what warden throws.