# Is it possible for begin .. rescue to NOT catch an exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a process that is within a `begin` `rescue` loop, that looks like this:

```
begin
  # do some stuff
rescue Exception => e
  Rails.logger.info "#{e.response.message}"
end
```

Is it possible for this to NOT catch an exception? For some reason my process is running, not throwing errors, but randomly not working.

Comment: Are you in production environment? Because you shouldn't see info logging as default there.

Comment: anything can happen if you rescue `Exception`. You should catch `StandardError`

Comment: _"not working"_ is rather vague, can you be more specific?

Comment: Ok, I'll update it too `StandardError` see what happens.. And "not working" is vague, that's really my problem. I don't know why, but the process in the `begin` section doesn't send to the remote API. But I don't know why.

Comment: How does `# do some stuff` look like?

Comment: There isn't really enough info to answer this; the problem would seem to be that your `begin` block is never reached (perhaps due to an unhandled exception further up the call chain).

Comment: @ChrisHeald hmm, good point..

Answer (score 1):

Just use :

```
# do some stuff
```

without any begin/rescue block, and see which Error comes out. Let's say it is `NoMethodError`. Maybe you have a typo in some of your code, like `"abc".spilt`.
Correct it. Try again, maybe you get `Errno::ECONNRESET`.

Try :

```
begin
  # do some stuff
rescue Errno::ECONNRESET => e
  Rails.logger.info "#{e.message}"
end
```

Rinse and repeat, but start from scratch. `rescue Exception` is just [too much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can temporary comment rescue block:

```
#begin
  ...
#rescue Exception => e
 #Rails.logger.info "#{e.response.message}"
```

or you can raise raise this exception in rescue:

```
begin
  do some stuff
rescue Exception => e
  Rails.logger.info "#{e.response.message}"
  raise e
end
```