# uninitialized Twilio::REST::LookupsClient

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio, lookup

I'm using `ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]`
rails: `Rails 5.1.3`

I have action in which I check a phone number if it is valid or not and action where I send message. 
the message action working perfectly but I get an error when I try to check a number. this is the action

```
def check_phone_number
    account_sid = Rails.application.secrets.twilio_sid
    auth_token = Rails.application.secrets.twilio_token
    @lookup_client = Twilio::REST::LookupsClient.new(account_sid, 
                     auth_token)
    response = @lookup_client.phone_numbers.get("#
               {params[:phone_number]}")
    begin
      response.phone_number
      render json: {'response' => 'ok'}
    rescue Exception => e
      if e.code == 20404
        render json: { 'error' => 'Invalid Number' }
      else
        render json: { 'error' => 'Invalid Number' }
      end
    end
  end
```

the error is `uninitialised Twilio::REST::LookupsClient`

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like you have installed the latest version of the Twilio gem. In this version there is no longer a `Twilio::REST::LookupsClient` all REST clients are part of the `Twilio::REST::Client` object. You also can make the request specifically, rather than having to call on a property of the phone number object you create.

Check out the documentation and examples of [making calls to the Lookup API with Ruby](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups?code-sample=code-lookup-with-e164-formatted-number&code-language=rb&code-sdk-version=5.x).

For right now, your code should look like this:

```
def check_phone_number
  account_sid = Rails.application.secrets.twilio_sid
  auth_token = Rails.application.secrets.twilio_token
  @lookup_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)
  phone_number = @lookup_client.lookups.phone_numbers(params[:phone_number])

  begin
    response = phone_number.fetch
    render json: {'response' => 'ok'}
  rescue Twilio::REST::RestError => e
    if e.code == 20404
      render json: { 'error' => 'Invalid Number' }
    else
      render json: { 'error' => 'Invalid Number' }
    end
  end
end
```

Note, I also replaced your `rescue Exception` because [it's a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby). Instead, you can `rescue Twilio::REST::RestError`.

For more on using the lookups API to validate phone numbers in Ruby, check out my blog post on [using Active Model Validations and Twilio Lookups](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/06/validate-ruby-objects-with-active-model-validations.html#h.iyaywics5y3j)

Answer (score 0):

Could be the first :: throwing it off. Try:

```
@lookup_client = Twilio::REST::LookupsClient.new(account_sid, 
                     auth_token)
```

instead of

```
@lookup_client = ::Twilio::Rest::Client.new account_sid, account_auth_token
```

Examples: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/blob/master/examples/examples.rb

Also, see https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/blob/master/lib/twilio-ruby/rest/client.rb - looks like REST should be capitalized.

Comment: no! do you even read my question? and i know from where you copy it.