# What is block_singleton_method in ruby ? why am i getting this error while exiting

Tags: ruby

below is the code which is called by the gtk closing action -->

```
def on_main_window_destroy(object)
  begin
  $client.send(':exit')
  Thread.kill $client.response
  rescue
    puts 'exiting'
  end
  Thread.kill $receiving_message
  Gtk.main_quit()
  exit
end
```

which results in this output.

```
app.rb:81:in `exit': exit
 from app.rb:81:in `on_main_window_destroy'
 from /home/user/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/gobject-introspection-3.1.8/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb:110:in `invoke'
 from /home/user/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/gobject-introspection-3.1.8/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb:110:in `block in define_singleton_method'
 from app.rb:97:in `<main>'
```

the program works fine .. and it doesn't create a mess for me .. but i want to know the reasons for these errors so that i can handle it.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Kernel#exit`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-exit) raises an exception to terminate the program, that looks like be the exception message you're asking about:

> Initiates the termination of the Ruby script by raising the SystemExit exception. This exception may be caught.

As for the `"block in define_singleton_method"` part of the stack trace, while ruby has a [`define_singleton_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-define_singleton_method), if you look at line 110 of that file specified, you'll see that the method you are in is also called `define_singleton_method` and you are inside a block in that method:

```
def define_singleton_method(klass, name, info)
  # ... 
  singleton_class.__send__(:define_method, name) do |*arguments, &block|
    arguments, block = prepare.call(arguments, &block) # <<< Line 110
    # ...
  end
end
```

I'm not sure why you're actually seeing that output instead of just exiting silently like you normally would, a possibility is that somewhere in the code, something is just rescuing the base `Exception`, instead of `StandardError`, which is [generally a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby), though they may be just logging/outputting and re-raising it (which as seen in some of those answers, is OK), it's all just speculation without digging around a lot further into the code (it might not even be in this gem)