# Ruby generic catch all error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, exception

Is there a way to catch any type of error the Ruby/Rails encounters?

I am making a network request. What I have seen so far is, it can return 404, timeout or even any empty response object?

I have handled them individually, it is not DRY, but is there a way to handle all these and those which I have not seen yet gracefully?

Many times even when the response object is analysed, sometimes it may not contain what I am looking for. Sure I can handle them individually.
 I am curious to know if it is possible to define a use case to work with, everything apart from it, which I have not imagined, is just thrown an exception and does not break my application.

Is generic error handling possible in Ruby?

Comment: Would you not be better off using something like [Better Errors](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors)?

Comment: @SRack, I also use Better Errors, but I believe OP is looking to handle requests from outside of the network?

Comment: Cheers Daryll, makes sense. Also, going to leave this here as very worthwhile reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby/10048406#10048406

Comment: @SRack There is a caveat there in BetterErrors, it discourages using it in production. I really dont want to be bothered about that. But I didn't know about BetterErrors. So thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes its absolutely possible, there are a couple of different levels of rescuing exceptions in Ruby, as noted by Daryll you can specify different exceptions that go to the same handler like

```
begin
  # potentially exception raising code
rescue Exception1, Exception2 => e
  # run code if Exception1 or Exception2 get raised
end
```

You can also catch StandardError, which most Exceptions that you would want to catch inherit from. This is a good option if your looking for a catch all, like try this and keep going no matter what.

```
begin
  # potentially exception raising code
rescue StandardError => e
  # run code if StandardError or anything that inherits from StandardError is raised (most errors)
end
```

You can also catch Exception (**Dangerous**), which every Exception inherits from (including StandardError). You pretty much never want to do this since things like SyntaxErrors, SignalExceptions (you can catch Control-C and prevent terminating your script with it) and other internal errors also inherit from Exception. See http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-exception-vs-standarderror-whats-the-difference/ for some more details

```
begin
  syntax exception
rescue => e
  puts "I even catch syntax errors!!!"
end
puts "I'll keep on executing though"
```

Comment: I have tried these but they don't catch Gem specific errors. Have to define for each of those classes.

Comment: Ahh. Sorry. Had a typo. So the best thing is to raise `StandradError`. This should give some piece of mind, right?

Comment: yeah I'd say rescuing `StandardError` is probably what your looking for. If it were me, I'd still handle exceptions vs empty / bad responses separately, since you wouldn't have a response to go through if there was an error. Although if I had the same logic regardless if there was an error or an empty response, I'd just throw that into a method and call them in both the rescue and when you don't find what your looking for in the response

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this? [Source.](http://mikeferrier.com/2012/05/19/rescuing-multiple-exception-types-in-ruby-and-binding-to-local-variable/)

```
begin
  rand(2) == 0 ? ([] + '') : (foo)
rescue TypeError, NameError => e
  puts "oops: #{e.message}"
end
```

If you are looking to implement these things in controllers, and want to DRY it up, try out rescuable. [Ruby API link.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from User::NotAuthorized, with: :deny_access # self defined exception
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, with: :show_errors

  rescue_from 'MyAppError::Base' do |exception|
    render xml: exception, status: 500
  end

  private
    def deny_access
      ...
    end

    def show_errors(exception)
      exception.record.new_record? ? ...
    end
end
```

Comment: Nice. Worth adding `StandardError` to those rescued to be comprehensive?

Comment: Based on [this article](http://blog.honeybadger.io/understanding-the-ruby-exception-hierarchy/), it's the default one :)

Comment: Ah, very handy. Cheers @DaryllSantos. +1

Comment: In the SO you have linked, one of the comments suggests that it is better to rescue from the Gem specific classes. Isn't that unmaintainable?

Comment: Also, does standalone Ruby have a DRY way to do these?

Comment: For gem specific errors--what you can do is to localize the parts of your app that interact with that gem, and rescuing and re-raising them to your own error classes. Read a bunch of articles on the Adapter pattern for 3rd party APIs (or code you don't own). [This was the first that showed up on Google for me.](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/rails-refactoring-part-i-the-adapter-pattern/)