# Catch exception raised by lib in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

I have module saved in `lib/rolify_roles.rb`

```
module RolifyRoles
  path = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'rolify_roles.yml')
  @config = YAML.load_file(path)

  def add_role(role, target = nil)
    raise "Role is not defined!" if RolifyRoles.config[role].nil?
    ...
  end
end
```

This lib is prepended by `models/user.rb` which using the `add_role` method.

Then in `controllers/users_controller.rb` i have method which uses the `add_role` method:

```
  def create_user_role
    authorize User
      role = params[:user][:rolify_role].to_sym
      resource_type = params[:user][:resource_type]
      resource_id = params[:user][:id]

      resource = nil
      resource = resource_type.constantize.find(resource_id) unless resource_type.blank? || resource_id.blank?


      respond_to do |format|
        if @user.add_role role, resource
          format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: "Role #{role} was successfully added." }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
        else
          format.html { render :show }
          format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end

    # Add_role exceptions
    rescue Exception => e
       format.html { render :show }
       format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }

  end
```

I am trying to catch the exception from the module `RolifyRoles` in the controller method.

But when the exception is raised (`Role is not defined!`) it ends up in the module and it's not handled by the controller.
`User#add_role  lib/rolify_roles.rb, line 31`

How can I handle this behavior in the controller?

Backtrace:
[image]

#### Edit:

I've tried to `rescue` from `RecordNotFound` error in controller like this:

```
  def create_user_role
    authorize User
    role = params[:user][:rolify_role].to_sym
    resource_type = params[:user][:resource_type]
    resource_id = params[:user][:id]

    # Catch RecordNotFound doesn't work
    begin
      resource = nil
      resource = resource_type.constantize.find(resource_id) if RolifyRoles.available_resources.include?(resource_type) && resource_id.present?
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      format.html { render :show }
      flash[:error] = e.message
    end
  end
```

And when the `resource_type.constantize.find(resource_id)` cannot find the record, its doesnt raise the `rescue` block.

```
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 46ms (ActiveRecord: 3.2ms)
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find RequestComment with 'id'=1:
 app/controllers/users_controller.rb:58:in `create_user_role'
```

Comment: First of all, [don't rescue `Exception`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby). Second, do you have `begin` keyword in `create_user_role` method, or not?

Comment: I used `Exception` only because of testing. Now the `begin` keyword is not used, but I tried it with the keyword and result was the same.

Comment: You will probably need to show the whole `create_user_role` method.

Comment: @MarekLipka i don't think the `begin` is needed here, e.g. `def foo; rescue; end` works fine. Also, Jan, I don't see why you're getting this behavior. Yes, please show the whole method.

Comment: @maxpleaner I didn't say it's needed, I asked if there is one.

Comment: @MarekLipka Question was edited with the whole method.

Comment: Ok, it still doesn't explain this behavior. So my next question: What is the backtrace of this error?

Comment: @MarekLipka backtrace was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved catching exception there [Why controller does not catch error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817923/why-controller-does-not-catch-error).

When the exception is caught at the `respond_to` block, then it works correctly.