# How do I rescue "invalid Unicode codepoint" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, error-handling

`s = "\u{d800}"` produces an error, `test.rb:1: invalid Unicode codepoint`, as expected. However,

```
begin
  s = "\u{d800}"
rescue Exception
  puts "oh no"
end
```

does the same thing, producing the error rather than an output of `oh no`. Is there a built-in way to rescue this, or would I have to hardcode valid ranges of Unicode codepoints to check validity?

Comment: I can confirm `SyntaxError` in 2.5.1 unfortunately a `SyntaxError` cannot be rescued in that fashion the only way you could rescue this error would be to "eval" that code e.g. `begin; eval('"\u{d800}"'); rescue SyntaxError; 'oh no';end;` but I would not recommend this. Can you explain a bit further how this is happening?

Comment: Unrelated, but never rescue `Exception`. Always rescue something more specific https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if a number is a valid unicode codepoint with [`chr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-chr)

```
0xd800.chr('UTF-8')
# RangeError (invalid codepoint 0xd800 in UTF-8)
```

Comment: Alternatively, without raising an exception: `[0xd800].pack('U').valid_encoding?`